# py.test boolean switch between parameterized fixtures

Tags: python, pytest

How can you switch between parameterizations without doing every combination in between? For example, the test below will run 24 tests (4*3*2 for `asdf`, `jkl` and `BOOLEAN` respectively).

But I just want to switch between `asdf` and `jkl` as outputs, so there should only be 7 tests total, because I just want `asdf_or_jkl` to return **one** of `asdf` or `jkl`'s parameterizations, not the product of the three arguments. Is it possible to do this using `py.test`'s fixtures, or do you need to do something else?

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=list('asdf'))
def asdf(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=list('jkl'))
def jkl(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def BOOLEAN(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def asdf_or_jkl(BOOLEAN, asdf, jkl):
    if BOOLEAN:
        return asdf
    else:
        return jkl

def test_2(asdf_or_jkl):
    assert asdf_or_jkl == 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you have the lists outside ? `l1=list('asdf')` and `@pytest.fixture(params=list1)`

Comment: Thanks for the input! With `params=[list1, list2]`, this creates 4 tests, two for the boolean, and two for the elements in the list of lists, so the element-wise tests are redundant. The lists are abstractions here, the actual test is using 5+ fixtures to parameterize `object1`, and I'd like to compare to the **different** 5+ fixtures parameterizing `object2`.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
import pytest


list1=list('ASDF')
list2=list('jkl')

def alternate(list1, list2):
    num = min(len(list1), len(list2))
    result = [None]*(num*2)
    result[::2] = list1[:num]
    result[1::2] = list2[:num]
    result.extend(list1[num:])
    result.extend(list2[num:])
    return result

@pytest.fixture(params=alternate(list1, list2))
def asdf_or_jkl(request):
    return request.param

def test_2(asdf_or_jkl):
    assert asdf_or_jkl == 0
```